# To 'Pan' in 3D modelling. Do you move the direction of the camera, or the camera itself?

Tags: opengl, 3d, viewport

We currently have some coursework at uni using OpenGL. Part of the coursework is to implement a 'pan' feature. However there is some confusion as to what 'panning' actually involves when speaking in terms of 3d modelling.

Is it;

**A:** Keeping the 'eyepoint'/'camera' in the same position, but changing the position it is looking towards. Much like 'panning' in photography when taking a panoramic shot.

**B:** Keeping the direction of the camera on the same axis, but moving the position of the 'eyepoint'/'camera' in free space perpendicular to the direction it is 'looking'

Answer (score 1):

"Pan" means to move the position of the camera without altering the pitch, roll or yaw, and to maintain the same distance from your subject - no "zooming".